# How to schedule async execution with different elapse times?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have 2 sets of jobs that need to be performed separately and can't run parallel. The jobs involve web communication so async is used.

Currently, I have `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`s set up to execute the batches with `Task.Run()`. To avoid the possible simultaneous execution, first I thought I can simply use a `lock() {}` inside the timers' `Tick` (I update the UI with countdown at ticks). Then realized that I need to `.Wait()` for the task to finish, otherwise it just exits the critical section.

Then I realized that all of this is running on the UI thread, so it's like those Elmer Fudd scenes where he points his rifle in one hole and the end comes out another pointing back at him.

Is there a simple nail-hammer approach to not block the UI thread while maintaining mutually excluded execution?

Here's a sample for one of the timers:

```
_timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };
_timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
{
    var timeSpan = _nextRun - DateTime.Now;
    if (timeSpan.Seconds >= 0)
    {
        UpdateCountdownMessage(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00} to next run.", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds));
    }
    else
    {
        lock (_runLock)
        {
            Task.Run(() => RunJobs(_batch1Jobs)).Wait();
        }
    }
};
```

To make it clearer, there is a 2nd timer, lets say it's called `_timer2`, that similarly updates a different countdown and runs `_batch2Jobs` when it reaches 0.

Comment: You question is vague. What are you actually trying to achieve here. Perhaps describe the actual problem. What is `batchJobs`? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get rid of `lock` and switch to [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
SemaphoreSlim _runLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

Then you can use something like this

```
_timer.Tick += async (sender, args) =>
{
    var timeSpan = _nextRun - DateTime.Now;
    if (timeSpan.Seconds >= 0)
    {
        UpdateCountdownMessage(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00} to next run.", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds));
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await _runLock.WaitAsync();
                try { RunJobs(_batch1Jobs); }
                finally { _runLock.Release(); }
            });
        }
        finally { _timer.Enabled = true; }
    }
};
```

Please note that you should never use `lock` or `Task.Wait` on the UI thread for a long running tasks. The UI code should use only `async/await` constructs.

Comment: This is the right approach, but because ticks can be delivered concurrently I would extend the critical section to the entire method. As it stands it is racy. Also, disabling a timer is racy and might not take immediately. Probably, no timer should be used. A Task.Delay loop would be better.

Comment: What's the advantage of the semaphore(slim) over the lock? That you can await to acquire it?

Comment: @usr OP is using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which IMO has no races. But of course there are alternatives.

Comment: Ah, a Forms timer. Right, no races there. But await gets off of the UI thread and that enabled multiple tick handlers to run concurrently from that point on. So it's still racy. You might get the following sequence for enabled: false, false, true, true.

Answer (score 0):

You should use tasks:

```
Task T1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {/*do work */});
Task T2 = T1.ContinueWith((antecedent) => {/*do work 2*/});
```

Comment: But I don't know if there's a continuation. There's a different timer object running for the separate batch.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. From your code, I see that you update the UI as long as _nextRun - DateTime.Now > 0 and when you reach to 0, you execute some jobs, so why don't you want to run these jobs in separate tasks?